# Getting errors when entering a vim file and tmux

Tags: python, macos, vim, tmux

I was trying to install a plugin for tmux called powerline. I was installing some thing on brew like PyPy and python.

Now when I try to open a vim file I get:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Python
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/vim
Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

and when I try to open tmux i get:

```
exited
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me very recently with pipenv. When I did brew update, it updated some packages and there was a mismatch with some of the python packages I might have installed using brew (and not pip). Easy way, I would suggest reinstalling some of those packages if that's not a huge problem.

Answer (score 0):

For future googlers, I was getting the same `dyld` error. Running `brew doctor` showed me the following:

```
Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
  vim
```

Running the following showed me which files it was complaining about:

`brew link --dry-run vim`

And if you're cool with overwriting those, this fixed it for me:

`brew link --overwrite vim`

Weird side note, running `vi` still had a similar error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Python
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/8.0-146/MacVim.app/Contents/bin/../MacOS/Vim
  Reason: image not found
[1]    58665 abort      vi
```

Still not sure what that issue was, but a lazy fix for that was `alias vi='vim'`